# Forgetting Torah study for Ben Sorer UMoreh - the biggest sin?

Tags: halacha-theory, torah-study, ben-sorer-umoreh

Concerning *בן סורר ומורה* the Yerushalmi Sanhedrin 43b (8:7) says:

> צפה הקב"ה שסוף של זה
>   עתיד לגמר ניכסי אביו ואת ניכסי אמו,
>   ויושב לו בפרשת דרכים,
>   ומקפח את הבריות,
>   והורג את הנפשות,
>   **וסופו לשכח את תלמודו**
>   ואמרה תורה מוטב שימו' זכאי ולא ימות חייב.

In my words: the degradation sequence of *בן סורר ומורה* is as following - he [starts with stealing from his parents and eating meat and drinking wine and then] will

- finish his parents money and then
- will eventually rob people and then
- will eventually kill people and then
- at the end he will forget his Torah study.

The Bavli In 72a, however, omits the last part.

Why according to this Yerushalmi forgetting one's Torah study is the final stage of degradation of a person?

Comment: And [ספרי](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.220.3) mentions none

Answer (score 1):

The *Pnei Moshe* writes:

> **פני משה מסכת סנהדרין פרק ח הלכה ז**
>
> גמ' וסופו לשכח את תלמודו. כלומר
> שמחמת ומהדר אחר לימודו והרגל הרגיל בו ואינו מוצא הורג
> את הנפשות לקחת ממונם. ויש לפותרו לשכח את תלמודו אלא דלא שייך כ"כ הכא:

The Pnei Moshe says to read it as, *because of* his forgetting his learning, he will become הרגל and do those things, and ultimately he will come to be a rasha.

So how do you read the Yerushalmi?

The Mishnah says:

> "בן סורר ומורה **נידון על שם סופו**"

So the Pnei Moshe, explaining the Gemara Yerushalmi, explains that since he forgot his learning (which would ordinarily exempt him, in this case, it is a different category and results in this negative behavior).

So that's the Gemara's point, that because he will be shown to have forgotten his learning, this will result in the chaos that which will lead him to do these aveiros.

And we judge him now because in the end, he will forget his learning.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I think the key phrase is still "ויש לפותרו לשכח את תלמודו אלא דלא שייך כ"כ הכא" - he admits it does not belong here. He admits the forgetfulness is either in the wrong place in this list or is wrongfully on the list at all as Bavli omits it. Please note the difference between לימודו and תלמודות - the first is his habits the last is his Torah study.